# How does lighting network ensure all parties cooperate

Tags: cryptography, trust, lightning-network

I somewhat understand the two way channels used in lightning. But I fail to see how trust is avoided.

If I'm the middle node I'm perfectly fine with forwarding a payment, if I received the payment first. The initial payer can reason that he will only make the payment if all intermediate nodes have shifted the payment to the receiver. It seems like until at least one party takes the risk the payment is in some kind of Mexican standoff.

How is this avoided / cryptograpically enforced?

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it: all the receiving parties can pull money out of their channel once they know a secret from the seller. To claim the funds on the final channel, the seller has to publish this secret.

Comment: Exactly. If the linked question resolves your question, you can vote to close it as a duplicate yourself. (Otherwise please specify what points you would like to see answered here still.) Thank you.

Comment: That will do for now. Edit: unfortunately I don't find how to mark this as duplicate